# Cant Get elements from ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

A while loop iterates throug a string , taking in 8 character substring at a time, get ASCII Code for each caracter and converting each byte to its binary representation, as 8 charactersso (8*8) Array for each 8 characters, Here is the code:

Message File contains:
1234567800000008

So the while loop runs twice as there are 16 characters,The code runs correctly until the binary values are inputed in the input block in the last for loop. When i add the inputblock in the arraylist, they arent the same values when i .get() them from the araylist again

```
        while(Message.length() != 0){
            substr=Message.substring(0, 8);
            bytes = substr.getBytes("ASCII");
            int[][] inputblock = new int[bytes.length][bytes.length];

                for(int i=0; i<bytes.length;i++){
                    binString =Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i]);

                        while (binString.length() < 8) {binString = "0" + binString;}

                      for(int j=0; j<bytes.length;j++){
                           int x=Character.digit(binString.charAt(j), 2);
                                inputblock[i][j] = x;

                            }
                          }     
             input.add(inputblock);  //// This is supposed to add each 64 bit (8*8) 
          Message=Message.replace(substr, "");        //Array to arraylist input. 
    System.out.print(substr + "+");


    }
```

For some reason when i come to print the contents of the arraylist, it prints out the actual characters of not the binary representation .. I dont know why ?

To output contenst

```
for (int i =0;i<input.size();i++){
     int[][] tmp = input.get(i);

     for(int j=0;j<input.size();j++){
         System.out.print(tmp[i][j]); }
       System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Output :
12345678+00000008+00
00

Comment: give us example of expected and actual output

Comment: And the code used to display the contents of the list.

Comment: Why is your `substr` assignment in its own block?

Comment: @Jon Skget.. Sorry that was a mistake, I removed them and got the same output

Comment: You've still got *really* odd indentation and whitespace choices (statements directly after a closing brace? Really?), and you still haven't given us a short but complete example. If you could tidy up your question with a short but complete, well-formatted, clear example you're likely to get an answer very quickly... and you may well find the problem while you're preparing the question.

Comment: How about that .. I edited again, I am really new to java and i could really use some help

Answer (score 0):

You mention "getting elements from an ArrayList" in your question, but I can't see you reading from `input` anywhere (assuming that's the list in this case).

The value printed out will always be `substr` followed by a literal `+` character, as this is the only thing you ask your program to print out (in the final line of the while loop).  The value of `substr` is set at the start of the loop to be the eight actual characters, so this behaviour seems appropriate.

If you want to print out the binary values, you'll need to convert `input` into a string in whatever format you're after, and pass *that* to `System.out.println()`.

---

**EDIT** with the extra information of how you're displaying the relevant output, there is a bug in your `input`-printing method.

You're declaring both for loops as:

```
for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
```

(and the same for `j`).  So both counter variables go from 0 to `input.size` - which is 2, as there are 2 characters.  As a result, you print out the first two bits of the first two bytes - `00` and `00`.

What you ought to be doing AIUI is iterating fully over both dimensions of the `tmp` array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
   int[][] tmp = input.get(i);

   for(int j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < tmp[j].length; k++) {
         System.out.print(tmp[j][k]);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: After getting the inputblock for the first eight characters I added it to input list.. I dont understand why it contains the actual characters, not the bits

Comment: I've updated my answer - you're not printing `input` correctly, which is why you only get `00 00`.  (Bear in mind that the initial `12345678+00000008+` output comes from the first bit of code where you call `println(substr)`, so it's wrong to conclude from this that `input` contains the actual characters - you can in fact see that it doesn't from the four bits that *are* output.)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except the following code...

```
for (int i =0;i<input.size();i++){
     int[][] tmp = input.get(i);

     for(int j=0;j<input.size();j++){
         System.out.print(tmp[i][j]); }
       System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Replace this code with the following code...

```
for (int[][] tmp :input.size();){

    for(int i=0; i< tmp.length; i++)
        for(int j=0;j<tmp.length;j++){
            System.out.print(tmp[i][j]); 
        }
       System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Everything else is correct